# Como formatar datas em python?

Tags: python

Quando eu faço assim:

```
  data = input('data [d/m/Y]: ')    
  print(data)

  data2 = datetime.strptime(data, "%d/%m/%Y")

  print(data2)
```

me retorna assim:

```
data [d/m/Y]: 17/08/2018

17/08/2018

2018-08-17 00:00:00
```

como faço para formatar as data sendo dd/mm/aaaa e não aparecer o tempo junto?

Answer (score 9):

O método [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) serve para fazer o *parsing* (provavelmente por isso o P) de uma data em um determinado formato. Ou seja, ele recebe uma string, faz o parsing e retorna um objeto [`datime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

Para transformar um objeto `datetime` em uma string novamente você pode usar:

- O método [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) para retornar uma string no formato desejado.

  ```
  minha_data.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  ```
- Usar o método [`datetime.__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__format__) (*format protocol*):

  - com a função [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#format).

    ```
    format(minha_data, "%d/%m/%Y")
    ```
  - com [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

    ```
    "{:%d/%m/%Y}".format(minha_data)
    ```
  - ou com as [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) introduzidas no python 3.6

    ```
    f"{minha_data:%d/%m/%Y}"
    ```

<sup>Veja o código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-330477-6333).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Se você deseja usar print tenta assim:

```
import datetime

_data="12/09/2018"
_data2=datetime.datetime.strptime(_data, "%d/%m/%Y")
print(_data2)

2018-09-12 00:00:00

print("{}/{}/{}".format(_data2.day,_data2.month,_data2.year))

12/9/2018
```

Comment: Agradecemos a contribuição - sim, essa forma mais "manual" funciona - mas  o melhor mesmo é usar as funcionalidades de formatação de datas já disponibilizaas pelo objeto datetime - seja com o `.strftime` ou com o a sintaxe especial para o `.format` das strings.