# Como modificar data ddMMYYYY para dd/MM/YYYY em python

Tags: python

Tenho um dataframe que tem um coluna com a data no formato 01012017 formato String) e preciso modificar ela para 01/01/2017

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
data = pd.DataFrame(['01012017','02012017','03012017','01042017'])
data
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiUMP.png)

Preciso converter essas coluna de data para dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330458/como-formatar-datas-em-python

Answer (score 0):

```py
data[0] = pd.to_datetime(data[0], format='%d%m%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

- Altera a coluna para [datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime) com [**pd.to_datetime**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) com o formato de data na string.
- Converte os valores da coluna para um formato específico de data com [**dt.strftime**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).